# Scrolling Subtitle With ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

The following code works fine except 1 parameter:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.MP4 -i logo.png -i profile.png -filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-8:8,overlay=10:10,drawtext=fontfile=verdanab.ttf:text=HelloWorld:fontcolor=white:fontsize=12:bordercolor=black:borderw=5:x=65:y=30-text_h/2,subtitles=subtitle.srt:force_style='MarginV=25,MarginL=w-(t-4.5)*w/5.5'" -c:a copy output.MP4
```

The following part does not work:

```
MarginL=w-(t-4.5)*w/5.5
```

I added this section to be a scrolling subtitle. However, it has no effect.
It works on the 'drawtext' section but not on the 'force_style' section.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`force_style` does not support expressions.

Instead, convert the subtitles from SRT to ASS:

```
ffmpeg -i input.srt output.ass
```

Then use the [`\move` ASS tag](http://docs.aegisub.org/3.2/ASS_Tags/#movement) within the ASS file:

```
Dialogue: 0,0:00:00.00,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\move(100,150,300,350)}Hello world
```